# Requests.get duplicates host on google app engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, flask, python-requests

So I have a bit of code to get titles and cover images for a specific comic, when only giving in the release number of the comic.
Here's the code:

```
import httplib
from string import lower
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def findTitle(number):
    url = 'http://suskeenwiske.ophetwww.net/albums/4kl/lijst.php'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.text, "html.parser")
    for ol in soup.findAll('ol'):
        for li in ol.findAll('a', href=True):
            if str(number) in li['href']:
                return unicode(li.contents[0])


def findImage(number, title):
    host = 'http://www.suskeenwiske.be/comics/'
    parsed_title = lower(title).replace(" ", "-")
    path = str(number) + '-' + parsed_title
    url = host + path
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'singl-img'})[0]
    img = div.findAll("img")[0]
    img_url = img['src']
    return urlfetch.Fetch(img_url).content


def readNumbers(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    return [line.rstrip() for line in lines]


def getStatusCode(host, path="/"):
    try:
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
        conn.request("GET", path)
        return conn.getresponse().status
    except StandardError:
        return None
```

So here's the problem: When I run the code directly calling `findImage(150, findTitle(150))' it works fine, the image and title are retreived. However, when calling it from flask (running from the Google App Engine Launcher) the host is duplicated thus resulting in the error:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error('An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: http://www.suskeenwiske.behttp/www.suskeenwiske.be/comics/88-de-tamtamkloppers Error: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

I'm not sure why this happens but this only happens when running the code with the Googe App Engine launcher. When running the code directly (calling the function from the interpreter) it works fine.

Does anyone have a clue as to what I'm missing here? What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you running internet behind proxy? Is there proxy defined in the browser which is not being used?

Comment: This is a bug in the latest version of the SDK: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12123

Comment: @HimanshuMishra no proxy.

Comment: @Greg That seems to be indeed the case. They have a workaround but that seems not the right thing since it won't work on production then. I guess I'll have to wait until they patch it :(

Comment: Are you getting the error in production? If so, then you're experiencing something different.

Comment: @Greg It's just locally, running with the Google App Engine Launcher. Haven't tried deploying yet since the app doesn't work yet.